Is it possible to have a reference box in-between two paracol columns, in which the text goes around the box?
Hey! 
As the title says: "Is it possible to have a reference box in-between two paracol columns, in which the text goes around the box?" 
I'm using paracol to have original language english on the left side, and translated language on the right side. 
\begin{paracol}{2}
\small
Only inspiration for this kind of document is the original Convention, where the text was split in separate parts, however this is only in english and latvian language.

\switchcolumn

\small
Vienīgā iedvesma par šādu dokumentu ir no oriģinālās Konvencijas, kur teksts tika sadalīt vairākās daļās, katrā daļā bija sava valoda, tomēr šeit ir tikai divas valodas.
\end{paracol}

However, I want to know if it is possible to add lets say a 'reference box', which just is in the middle of the both columns, and the text goes around the box.
I have got so far in code, where I have to use three columns, but it is not the look I am going for, as the vertical separator is not exactly in the middle, but on both sides, which makes the document look 'bad'.
\begin{paracol}{3} % Start with the left colum
\small
The document is split in two parts, left part of the document is written in english, while the right part of the document is written in latvian. This has been made so for the purposes of easier understanding for the non-native speakers of english language.

\switchcolumn[1] % Switches to middle column

\referencebox{This is a reference with multiple lines of content that automatically adjusts.}

\switchcolumn[2] % Switches to right column

\small
Dokuments ir sadalīts divās daļās, kreisā puse ir uzrakstīta angļu valodā, kamēr labā puse ir latviešu valodā. Šis ir lielākoties uztaisīts tā, lai tie kuri nav angļu valodas dzimtie, varētu saprast tekstu labāk.
\end{paracol}

And this code is for the reference box, that I have, but should be better.
% Set reference box width to 20% of the page width
\newlength{\refboxwidth}
\setlength{\refboxwidth}{0.2\textwidth} % Adjust as needed

% Custom command for reference box
\newcommand{\referencebox}[1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \colorbox{navyblue}{%
            \parbox{\refboxwidth}{%
                \centering
                \color{white}
                \small
                \textbf{Ref:}\\
                \smallskip
                #1
            }
        }
    \end{center}
}

Any help appreciated!
Edit:
I've added a PDF file and an image of how my file currently looks like, and how the reference box would need to look like.
https://file.io/eVn9xNZXHR17
It's a small colored box, with a light colored text, you can see it in the image when clicking on the link.
The whole code for the document, I'm just experimenting with the look, and then I'll start with shortening code.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\img}[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{images/#2}}

% Define colors
\definecolor{navyblue}{RGB}{0,32,51}

% Page geometry
\geometry{
    top=0cm,
    bottom=.5cm,
    left=1cm,
    right=1cm,
    includehead
}

% Set reference box width to 20% of the page width
\newlength{\refboxwidth}
\setlength{\refboxwidth}{0.2\textwidth} % Adjust as needed

% Custom command for reference box
\newcommand{\referencebox}[1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \colorbox{navyblue}{%
            \parbox{\refboxwidth}{%
                \centering
                \color{white}
                \small
                \textbf{Ref:}\\
                \smallskip
                #1
            }
        }
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
% Title block with navy bar
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[!htb]{0.1\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \img[width=3.5cm,angle=90]{logo.png}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[!htb]{0.8\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \raggedright
    \textcolor{navyblue}{\fontsize{60}{68}\selectfont\textbf{MAIN TITLE}}\\[0.2cm]
    \textcolor{navyblue}{\fontsize{30}{34}\selectfont\textsc{A Beautiful Subtitle}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[!htb]{0.1\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \raggedleft
    \textcolor{navyblue}\small\textsc{10/25/2024}\\
    \textcolor{navyblue}\small\textsc{SUBJ.REL1}
\end{minipage}%

% Horizontal line
\vspace{0.5cm}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
\vspace{0cm}

% Airplane image
\noindent
\img[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{journal.jpg}
\vspace{0.5cm}
% Language headers

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \small\textbf{EN} \hfill \small\textbf{The Preface \hspace{0.5em}|\hspace{0.5em} Priekšvārds} \hfill \small\textbf{LV}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm}

% Begin parallel columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}

\begin{paracol}{3} % Start with the left colum

\small
\lipsum[50]

\switchcolumn[1] % Switches to middle column

\referencebox{This is a reference with multiple lines of content that automatically adjusts.}

\switchcolumn[2] % Switches to right column

\small
\lipsum[50]

\end{paracol}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\small
\lipsum[120]

\switchcolumn

\small
\lipsum[120]

\end{paracol}


\vfill
% Horizontal line
\vspace{0.5cm}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.25pt}
\vspace{0cm}
\noindent\footnotesize
\centering
Document of "Company". Any unauthorized disclosure, use or dissemination, either in whole or in part is prohibited and \\ may be unlawful unless "Company" has authorized it in writing

\end{document}

I'll check the Werner's recommendation, and then give you any updates if any. Thanks Guys!

Welcome. // Can you please provide some graphic mockup about how your result should look like? // A way to create such a layout, with appropriate flow of text could be using this nice package: https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram . It's more in the direction of DTP, i.e. frame-based layout, and its learning curve is somewhat steep in the beginning. // However, once we can also see, what you have in mind, I'm sure there will arise some good solutions for you. // Thank you

Have a look at this: Two-column text with circular insert

BTW: Please try to convert your code snippets into something we can copy and compile. I.e. at the moment we'd miss the preamble, some dummy text (try e.g. https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum or https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext). Will make things easier for all involved. Thank you

You can add a two column insert using \switchcolumn[col]*[text] (see section 7.2).  Not as fancy as wrapping text around a box, but it serves the same function.

Hey guys!
I tried to use the pullquote package, however it clashes with other packages, like with microtype. I'll try the flowfram package, but as I see it could take some time. Thank you guys for ideas!

This overlaps the columns and the insert.  It uses \hangindent to wrap the text around the box.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\img}[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{images/#2}}

% Define colors
\definecolor{navyblue}{RGB}{0,32,51}

% Page geometry
\geometry{
    top=0cm,
    bottom=.5cm,
    left=1cm,
    right=1cm,
    includehead
}

% Set reference box width to 20% of the page width
\newlength{\refboxwidth}
\setlength{\refboxwidth}{0.2\textwidth}% Adjust as needed
\newlength{\refboxheight}

% Custom command for reference box
\newcommand{\referencebox}[1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \sbox0{%
          \colorbox{navyblue}{%
            \parbox{\refboxwidth}{%
                \centering
                \color{white}%
                \small
                \textbf{Ref:}\\
                \smallskip
                #1
            }%
          }%
        }\usebox0
        \global\refboxheight=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0+2\baselineskip\relax
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}

\small
\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn[0]*[\referencebox{This is a reference with multiple lines of content that automatically adjusts.}\par]
\vspace{-\refboxheight}%
\hangindent=-\dimexpr 0.5\refboxwidth+0.5\columnsep\relax
\hangafter=-\numexpr \refboxheight/\baselineskip\relax
\lipsum[50]

\switchcolumn % Switches to right column
\vspace{-\refboxheight}%
\hangindent=\dimexpr 0.5\refboxwidth+0.5\columnsep\relax
\hangafter=-\numexpr \refboxheight/\baselineskip\relax
\lipsum[50]

\switchcolumn*
\lipsum[120]

\switchcolumn
\lipsum[120]

\end{paracol}

\end{document}


Thank you for the recommendation!
It actually works great, but I'll continue looking, because the longer the text the longer the reference box, and the main text in both columns keep leaving a space.
